# how to make mockito ignore argument's value

Tags: mockito

I have seen that in `Mockito`, the `when` method is passed a method (say `m`) and the exact arguments which the `m` should be called with. Eg.

```
when(calcService.add(10.0,20.0)).thenReturn(30.00);
```

Above `30` is returned only if `add` is called with `10` and `20`. Otherwise when returns something undefined.

Is it possible to return `30` irrespective of what argument values are passed to `add`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, take a look on [ArgumentMatchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html). You could use

```
when(calcService.add(anyDouble(), anyDouble())).thenReturn(30.00);
```

for non null values, or

```
when(calcService.add(any(Double.class), any(Double.class))).thenReturn(30.00);
```

or something similar, depending on the actual type of your method input attributes.

Comment: Thanks. Wondering is UUID a Double? Could I use anyDoublt where a UUID is expected?

Comment: @ManuChadha UUID is NOT a double. I just used double in my answer since values in your question were float/double. There is for example matcher `any()` but the mockered method of course restricts wwhat matchers you can use. So if your method takes `double` you can not pass `UUID`, i think. I fyour method takes `UUID` as param then `any(UUID.class)` or so.